# How to populate a referenced document from `this` object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using NodeJS, MongoDB, and Mongoose. I am able to populate a referenced document if I use `findById(this.id)`, but not using `this` directly:

```
IssuanceSchema.methods.getOrganizationName = async function() {

  let issuance = await Issuance.findById(this.id).populate('organization');
  console.log(issuance);
  let temp = this.populate('organization');
  console.log(temp);

  console.log(issuance.organization.displayName());
  console.log(temp.organization.displayName());
  // ...
}
```

The log shows:

```
{
  _id: 5e849ca9b07ed81bd2eaad89,
  organization: {
    _id: 5e80a19d8c910f196c11673c,
    ...
  },
}
{
  _id: 5e849ca9b07ed81bd2eaad89,
  organization: 5e80a19d8c910f196c11673c,
}
SomeName
(node:10231) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: temp.organization.displayName is not a function
```

How can I populate the referenced document directly without the round-about `findById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are simply missing a call to `execPopulate()`. In your case that would be:

```
let temp = this.populate('organization').execPopulate();
```

Check out [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document):

> If you have an existing mongoose document and want to populate some of its paths, you can use the `Document#populate()` method. Just make sure you call `Document#execPopulate()` to execute the `populate()`.